# How to enable tablet-style scrolling on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, scrolling, touchscreen, internet-explorer-11

We have 40 CYPRUS All-in-One touchscreen terminals from Pioneer Solutions which we're using on our factory floor for production tracking. By default, they're all running in Desktop mode. We're now rolling out a web-based work instruction system (Dozuki.com) and are finding it very annoying to scroll web sites in both Internet Explorer 11 and Google Chrome. Having turned on Tablet Mode in Windows 10, I was expecting Internet Explorer to behave like a tablet, but when I drag my finger across the screen it just selects all the text and images between the two points.

Thinking that the problem might be Internet Explorer 11 (Edge is not permitted by corporate IT), we installed Google Chrome, but it behaves the same way. I did some Googling for solutions and found suggestions from 2019Q2 to go into chrome://flags and modify some settings, including "Touch Optimized UI" and "Enable touch events", but those settings do not exist in the current version of Chrome. I have tried enabling "Touch UI layout" and "Touch initiated drag and drop" but the scrolling issue persists.

I've also investigated whether this might be a driver configuration issue. It is using eGalaxTouch, but nothing in the configuration utility is jumping out at me.

Is this an issue of using the desktop versions of these web browsers instead of a Windows 10 native version? I'm not super familiar with this part of Windows 10.

Comment: All of the browsers I've used in Windows 10 support touch scrolling when I've used them - both Edge variants, IE, Chrome. I'm not familiar with the touch devices you have, but one thought I have is that these touch devices are presenting themselves to the operating system as mice, and are really translating your touch input into mouse inputs. Much like using modern tablet RDP client to connect to a Windows XP remote desktop.

Comment: This thought crossed my mind too. I'm going to contact the manufacturer and see what they have to say.

Comment: The eGalaxTouch driver that is currently installed emulates a mouse device. The manufacturer has suggested uninstalling the driver and restarting the system to allow the native Windows driver to take over.

Comment: Good luck. Hopefully that takes care of it. We have a point of sale system in our cafeteria that does this. It's a touch screen, but when you tap something, it's really just moving the mouse pointer there and sending a mouse click.